# Apexcharts reset zoom to relative time-range

Tags: grafana, apexcharts

I am using apexcharts on a Grafana custom panel. When using the "reset zoom" button, I would like to get redirected to a relative time-range (i.e., last 7 days, last 12 hours, etc.).

Originally, the reset zoom redirects to a zero time-range, I've managed to insert an event that resets the zoom to an absolute time-range

```
    beforeResetZoom: function (_, f) {
            const date = new Date();
            return {
              xaxis: {
                min: date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7),
                max: Date.now()
              },
            };
          },
```

but I cannot figure out if there is a way to reset it to a relative one.
Inserting "now", "now-7d", etc. to the min/max fields returns an invalid date on Grafana.